# Ruby: Difference between declaring variable before and after while loop?

Tags: ruby, object, undefined

I was working on a certain problem when I noticed that what threw everything off was that I had declared a variable outside of the while loops. The variable in question is sub_string = 1. It seems that I am required to declare it after the first while loop, right before it actually comes into play in the second while loop. By declaring it early, the loop somehow can only pick up on palindromes that begin on string[0] and, yet, can be of any length. For the life of me, I am unsure as to why it behaves in this manner, as I am declaring the length of the slice (not the starting position).

Forgive me if I am missing out on something incredibly basic here, as I am rather new to coding in general.

Here's the code in question (ommitted the definition of the palindrome? check method).

```
def longest_palindrome(string)
  idx = 0
  longest = nil
  #substring_string = 1  ; declaring it early seems to cause weird issues to show up
  while idx < string.length
    substring_length = 1 #I have to declare the substring_length here

    while (idx + substring_length) <= string.length
      substring = string.slice(idx, substring_length)
      if palindrome?(substring) && (longest == nil || substring.length > longest.length)
    longest = substring
    print substring_length
  end

  substring_length += 1
end

  idx += 1
  end

  return longest
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> Scenario 1: **substring_length defined inside while loop**

```
def longest_palindrome(string)
  idx = 0
  longest = nil
  while idx < string.length
    substring_length = 1
    while (idx + substring_length) <= string.length
      # palindrome
      substring_length += 1 
    end
    idx += 1
  end
  longest
end
```

- When this method is called on an object, execution control flow moves to the first `while` loop. `while idx < string.length`
- Inside that loop, you **initialize** `substring_length` to `1`
- Code then moves into a nested loop `while (idx + substring_length) <= string.length`
- Inside the nested loop, the palindrome method is called, then `substring_length` is **incremented by 1**. This code runs until its condition returns false `(idx + substring_length) < string.length`. The implication of this is that once this inner loop ends, `substring_length` is **ALWAYS** going to be a value **greater than 1**
- Once this inner loop ends, control goes back to the outer `while` loop. Now the first line of the code **reassigns** `substring_length` to `1`. In essence no matter the value of `substring_length` at the end of the inner loop, once control flow goes back to the outer loop, that value is discarded as you set `substring_length` to **1**

> Scenario 2: **substring_length defined outside while loop**

```
def longest_palindrome(string)
  idx = 0
  longest = nil
  substring_length = 1
  while idx < string.length
    while (idx + substring_length) <= string.length
      # palindrome
      substring_length += 1 
    end
    idx += 1
  end
  longest
end
```

- When this method is called on an object, `substring_length` **is initialized to 1** and then execution control flow moves to the first`while` loop. `while idx < string.length`
- If the condition is true, control flow moves to the second loop, the `inner` loop
- Inside the inner loop, the palindrome method is called, then `substring_length` is **incremented by 1**. This code runs until its condition returns false `(idx + substring_length) < string.length`. Just like in **scenario 1**, the implication of this is that once this inner loop ends, `substring_length` is **ALWAYS** going to be a value **greater than 1**
- Once this inner loop ends, control goes back to the outer `while`
  loop. This time there is no initialization statement, so the value of `substring_length` at the end of the inner loop is **the same value** used when control goes back to the outer loop.

Lets try and use an example

**Scenario 1**

```
longest_palindrome('him')
idx = 0; substring_length = 1; string.length = 3
while (0 < 3) # the outer loop condition is true,
substring_length = 1

# while (idx + substring_length) < string.length
while (0 + 1) < 3 # inner loop condition is true
# run code block, increment substring_length by 1, substring_length is NOW 2

while (0 + 2) < 3 # inner loop condition is still true
# run code block, increment substring_length by 1, substring_length is NOW 3

while (0 + 3) < 3 # inner loop condition fails, substring_length = 3

# Go to line after end of inner loop
increase idx by 1 # idx = 1

# Go back to outer loop
set substring_length to 1 # substring_length is NO MORE 3

# while (idx + substring_length) < string.length
while (1 + 1) < 3 # run code block, increment substring_length by 1, substring_length is NOW 2
while (1 + 2) < 3 # condition fails
..... and so on
```

**Scenario 2**

```
longest_palindrome('him')
idx = 0; substring_length = 1; string.length = 3
while (0 < 3) # the outer loop condition is true,

# while (idx + substring_length) < string.length
while (0 + 1) < 3 # inner loop condition is true
# run code block, increment substring_length by 1, substring_length is NOW 2

while (0 + 2) < 3 # inner loop condition is still true
# run code block, increment substring_length by 1, substring_length is NOW 3

while (0 + 3) < 3 # inner loop condition fails, substring_length = 3

# Go to line after end of inner loop
increase idx by 1 # idx = 1

# Go back to outer loop. Remember substring_length =3

# while (idx + substring_length) < string.length
while (1 + 3) < 3 # condition is false. Inner loop is NOT EXECUTED

# Go to line after end of inner loop
increase idx by 1 # idx = 1

# Go back to outer loop while (idx < string.length)
while (1 < 3) # outer loop condition is true

# Go to inner loop while (idx + substring_length) < string.length
while (1 + 3) < 3 # Once again condition is false and inner loop is NOT EXECUTED

# Go to line after end of inner loop
increase idx by 1 # idx = 1
```

As you can see in this scenario, the inner loop stops getting executed because `substring_length` does not get reassigned to 1 and the condition continually fails.

Comment: Huh. I think I'll have to re-read your explanation a few times to get it down pat, but thanks a lot for responding!

Comment: Hey @Tony, I edited my answer. Hopefully this gives you a better understanding.

Comment: Your explanation was great to begin with. Your formatting made it very friendly to see what the key difference was between the two scenarios at hand. My comment cut off short and I somehow didn't catch that ( nor does it seem that I am able to edit comments). Thank you for your time. I'll need to google up how you were able to show each loop output like that (as I've been using print as part of my loop all along for bits of information as to what the code was doing).